# Distance from linear combinations over the integers

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers, integers

I'm a bit confused with the inequalities over the integers, my question is if $a\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ is fixed and $q\neq0$. How do I prove $|am+n+q|\geq \epsilon$ if $am+n+q\neq 0$, where $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$? Or is this not true? That is, is the distance of a real number $q$ to the set $(a\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z})\backslash\{q\}$ greater than zero if $q$ is not zero? Why is it $0$ when $q$ is zero?

Comment: It is not true. You could let for example $am+bn$ be $-5$ and $q$ be $4$.

Comment: I've edited it. I'm justtrying to understand if linear combinations over the integers of real numbers can get arbitrarly close to another real number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture is wrong. I will prove that $\{am + n: n,m \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ for any given fixed irrational $a$, which is exactly the negation of your conjecture. By the way the assumption that $q \neq 0$ doesn't change anything.

Let's fix any natural number $i$. Without loss of generality we assume $a \geq 0$. We will prove that there exist nonzero integers $m_0, n_0$ such that $|am_0 + n_0| \leq \frac{1}{2^i}$. It's easy to see that this is equivalent to what we actually want to prove, because $a$ is irrational, so $|am_0 + n_0| \neq 0$. So if we prove this "lemma", then $am_0 + n_0$ will be a small nonzero number and we can mutiply it by some integer to get $\frac{1}{2^i}$-close to any given real number.

So let's consider $$A := \{a, 2a,  3a, 4a, ..., (2^{i}+1)a\}$$ and look at the binary representation of members of $A$ to the $i$th place after the decimal point (f.i. for $i=4$ and a number $101.001010$ we look at $(0,0,1,0)$; we don't care about the part before the decimal, only the part after the decimal up to $i$th place).
Now we have $|A| = 2^{i}+1 > 2^i$, so there will be two different numbers in $A$ with exactly the same sequence of digits up to $i$th point after the decimal point. Let's say that these are $na$ and $ma$.
Now we see that $m_0:= |n - m|$ and $n_0:= -\lfloor m_0a \rfloor$ are the nonzero integers for which $|am_0 + n_0| \leq \frac{1}{2^i}$.

This ends the proof of the "lemma" and thus also proves my original claim about density.